# How to return Json result without double quotes?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, return, jsonresult

I use this action in controller:

```
public JsonResult DoSomething(int id )
{
  char result = '0';
  ....
  return this.Json( result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
}
```

Results are in double quotes:  **"0"**, **"1"**, **"2"** etc.

How can I get results without double quotes as **0**, **1**, **2** etc. ?

Comment: you're defining result to be a `char`, which in json-land is a string... so you get quotes. If you want `0` without quotes, make it a number (e.g. an int). @jon: in json, strings must be quoted, but numbers and numerical keys aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the correct type for `result` and you should get a non-string for the integer.